# Is every planar graph without triangles 3-colorable?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, coloring

In other words, can a planar graph without k3 have a chromatic number larger than 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, every triangle-free planar graph is 3-colorable. This is known as [Grötzsch's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch%27s_theorem).

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that the theorem does not generalize in the natural way, as evidenced in answers to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225872/can-a-graph-be-non-3-colourable-without-having-k4-as-a-sub-graph